# Ubuntu 64 bit download flagged as phishing site

Tags: 64-bit, downloads, antivirus

While downloading Ubuntu 64 bit iso, my anti-virus program (kaspersky) flagged the site as a phishing site. I was at 585mb of the 708mb file size when the alarm came up.
Has anyone else had this issue and is there a more secure server to download the software?

Comment: What URL is it downloading from?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a problem with the [mirror](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/M/mirror_site.html) it is using. Mirrors are usually calculated to give the fastest internet speed for your location. The mirror I get is:
http://mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net/ubuntu-releases//saucy/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso

Anyway, you can download it directly from here:
http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/

It does not seem to use mirrors, as it gives this as the link for the `amd64.iso`:
http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso